# Modify a String by modifying its byte array representation

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoding, byte

## What I want to do

I want to create a Rainbow Table for MD5 hashs of all 4 characters Strings (or any number but that's irrelevant). I want to generate the byte array representation of those 4 charater strings.
For performance, I don't want to just create the `String` and call a `getBytes` on it. **I want to modify the byte sequence to make it the representation of the next string**.

Example:

```
byte[] firstString = "aaaa".getBytes(ENCODING);
// I hash and store firstString
byte[] nextString = ???
System.out.println(new String(nextString));
// I want it to print "aaab". This should go up to "aaaz" and then go to "aaba". I'll add the number after.
```

## What I did

I tried to increment it by manipulating the binary (from an answer on SO):

```
byte[] toDecode = "aaaa".getBytes(ENCODING);

int cpt = 0;
String s;
boolean carry;

while (cpt < 15) {
      cpt ++;
      System.out.println(toDecode); // prints the byte array

      s = DigestUtils.md5Hex(toDecode);

      System.out.println(new String(toDecode + " : " + s);
      carry = true;
      // Yeah, I know this for can be simplified with a break, I'll do it later :(
      for (int i = (toDecode.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (carry) {
                if (toDecode[i] == 0) {
                    toDecode[i] = 1;
                    carry = false;
                } else {
                    toDecode[i] = 0;
                    carry = true;
                }
            }
      }
}
```

### Result

```
[B@4e25154f //The byte value, that's ok  
aaaaaaaa : 3dbe00a167653a1aaee01d93e77e730e // The string and its hash  
[B@4e25154f // Here, the byte array doesn't seem to be different!  
         : 7dea362b3fac8e00956a4952a3d4f474  
[B@4e25154f   
       X : 7dea362b3fac8e00956a4952a3d4f474
[B@4e25154f 
      X  : 7dea362b3fac8e00956a4952a3d4f474
[B@4e25154f
      XX : 7dea362b3fac8e00956a4952a3d4f474
[B@4e25154f
     X   : 7dea362b3fac8e00956a4952a3d4f474
```

The `X` represent a little square with 0 and 1 in it, I can't paste it, they don't get printed in the question. They move like binary does: first element, the second, then both second and first, then third, etc...
My guess is that I'm somehow modifying the bits, which leads to this change.
What I don't understand is:

- Why isn't the byte array changing?
- What should I do to change the byte array so it represents the next String

On the side, if you have any comments to the method I'm using, feel free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[B@4e25154f` is just the default `toString()` implementation of a `byte[]`. Since you're using the same `byte[]` it won't change. The internal contents of the `byte[]` do change.

The `for` loop seems to be completely broken logically. If you want to turn `a` to a `b`, you can just call `toDecode[i]++`. Your version seems to be trying to manipulate the values as if they were bits, so you get those `0` and `1` chars that can't be displayed.

You probably want to keep a set of valid characters depending on what you want (`[a-zA-Z0-9]` at least I'd imagine, and any special characters you want). Then you can work with an array of indexes to your `validChars[]`, with `0` representing the first character.

Then you just need to loop each array index from `0` to `validChars.length` and handle the carry. After each increment iteration you can map the indexes to the bytes from your `validChars` to get the resulting `byte[]` containing valid, displayable characters that may be used in passwords.

Also this isn't actually a [Rainbow Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) since you just seem to want to precalculate all the hashes, whereas rainbow tables do a space/time trade-off. With the recent technological advantages there's no need to trade time for space, as you can buy several terabyte SSD disks for small change, so Rainbow Tables are pretty much extinct.